# Laravel eloquent - how to return query from models without creation of models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I ran this query:

```
$us = User::query()->with('roles','comments', 'posts')->get();

return response()->json($us);
```

the problem is this took almost a second to return. The queries are when looking at [laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) super fast. E.g. they all together take less than 50ms.

but, the return does take ~1000ms. I assume it's the instantiation that takes so much time. E.g. all thousand models have to be instantiated, then transformed to json, then returned.

What is a way to do this, without models, and without having to manually write joins? isn't there some function `asPlainArray()`

```
$us = User::query()->asPlainArray()->with('roles','comments', 'posts')->get();
```

Notice:

```
->get()->toArray()
```

won't work, because get first returns the models, then array is called. So might even take LONGER

Comment: Eloquent's active-record approach is not a very good choice, if you want speed, especially for large data sets. Nor is PHP itself for that matter. Also, I don't know how they implement it, but what might take a lot of time is pairing results of User's relation queries (roles, comments, posts) with User models.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký you could be right. That is why I ask for a workaround. Maybe I can just call `->toSql()` and run the sql in a raw query?

Comment: Doesn't `toSql()` return string? That way bindings wouldn't be resolved.

Comment: Well, you could retrieve the bindings as well with `->getBindings()` but the problem is that  `->toSql()` will only return the first SQL for `User`, without any joins. As `with` runs selects separately.

Comment: Get the bindings and run the pure SQL with ```DB::raw```. It will return an array!

Comment: maybe this method will work for you: https://stitcher.io/blog/php-preload-benchmarks

Comment: @JonathanMartins wont work with eager loading like in my example. Returns `select * from user` no roles, comments nothing.

Comment: I looked at laravels code, the culprit is their `eagerLoadRelation` function in the query builder. This builder afaik _needs_ the model to be populated, accesses then the models relation to figure out what to eager load. So chicken egg problem you cannot get the raw sql of something without creating the model, if that thing needs the model to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, eager loading does not work with ```DB:raw```. I have the impression that your performance problem is exactly the eager loading. If you have a lot of rows to eager load, the whole process gets slow. If you want performance, you cannot scape ```DB:raw``` with joins and custom selects.

Comment: well, fair enough. But where is the explanation to get the same result as laravel does? say you have multiple joins, but the query builder won't return the same structure as laravel does. Which means I make my stuff more and more complex. What I want is the same json structure after my DB::raw as I would get when doing it normal eloquent way. Not even sure how to do that...

Comment: like I would do `DB::table('users')->join('roles',...)` will _not_ result in instances like `[{name: 'dirk', ..., roles: [...]}]` but will return flat sql results. The question is: is there an easy way to get the same structure with fast sqls?

Comment: You can normalize that before sending it out. You cannot have everything every time, sometimes there is a trade that we must make. Yes, your code will be more complex, but performance-wise, your code will run faster!

Comment: "normalizing" would be a lot of work in that case though. Like, nobody figured a streamlined way for it that works with mysql? probably the easiest to get the same structure, is to run the same sqls actually... e.g. no joins at all. Just ` where id IN (2,3,6254)`

Answer (score 0):

The query that you got:

```
$us = User::query()->with('roles','comments', 'posts')->get();

return response()->json($us);
```

That is gonna be slow because it is getting all data from the `users` table. In addition, returning too much data from a single API call tend to fail.

As far as I know, for this sort of API calls, companies always paginate the results. The client can always get more results by providing `offset` and `limit`.

```
$us = User::query()->with('roles','comments', 'posts')->paginate();

return response()->json($us);
```

If you don't want the results to be hydrated to models, you might use the `DB` facade. But I don't think you can eager load relationships.

```php
DB::table('users')->select(...)
    ->join(...)
    ->join(...)
    ->join(...)
    ->get();
```

Comment: pagination making things more complicated. Better would be, it just works with great speed. Like, now you have to paginate. And you have to implement a server side filter etc instead of a html table with javascript filter. _everything_ got with one beat, a lot harder. The problem with `DB::` is that it returns different structure to laravels eloquent. E.g. it returns flat row data, and duplicate names, will cause errors. Like I would be fine using `DB::` but not if the result actually looks very different to what laravel returns and there is no way to transform.